# How to use Banner & Interstitial Ads in Android TV application?

Tags: android, admob, ads, android-tv

I want to use AdMob ads in Android TV but Official Document has not Android TV example.

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

How can I use AdMob ads in Android TV app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AdMob SDK does not officially support Android TV at this time.

Check this url: https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/7NMy67EzPMg